# Loopback how to handle RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded?

Tags: loopbackjs

I need to access some data throughout in the loopback application. For that i have just appended data in accessToken. And it is accessible fine.

But some time my linux server gets shut down. While looking in the forever logs i found some error which is saying Maximum call size exceeded.

```
module.exports = function (options) {
        return function storeCurrentUser(req, res, next) {
            if (!req.accessToken) {
                next();
            }else{
                app.models.User.findById(req.accessToken.userId, function (err, user) {
                    if (err) {
                        next(err);
                    }
                    if (!user) {
                        next(new Error('No user with this access token was found.'));
                    }else{                   
                        var PM = app.registry.getModel("PersistedModel");
                        PM.observe("access", function (ctx, next) {
                            ctx.options.data = req.accessToken.data; // each error showing this line
                            next();
                        });
                        next();
                    }
                });      
            } 
        };
    };
```

### Log error :

Unhandled error for request GET /api/ACLs?filter={%22where%22:{%22principalId%22:%22admin%22}}&access_token=4N8gnOrgGUpjVDohYsNj9pWBruUFhif8NCjg95RoITxU1xDGwvcgFwTGjxNbqs9C: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at replenish (/home/ubuntu/hms/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:870:27)
    at iterateeCallback (/home/ubuntu/hms/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:866:17)
    at /home/ubuntu/hms/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:843:16
    at /home/ubuntu/hms/server/middleware/store-current-user.js:62:25
    at notifySingleObserver (/home/ubuntu/hms/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:160:22)
    at /home/ubuntu/hms/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3025:16
    at replenish (/home/ubuntu/hms/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:881:17)
    at iterateeCallback (/home/ubuntu/hms/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:866:17)
    at /home/ubuntu/hms/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:843:16
    at /home/ubuntu/hms/server/middleware/store-current-user.js:62:25
    at notifySingleObserver (/home/ubuntu/hms/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:160:22)
    at /home/ubuntu/hms/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3025:16
    at replenish (/home/ubuntu/hms/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:881:17)
    at iterateeCallback (/home/ubuntu/hms/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:866:17)
    at /home/ubuntu/hms/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:843:16
    **at /home/ubuntu/hms/server/middleware/store-current-user.js:62:25**

Since I have multiple models, I am getting same Maximum size exceeded error for different file.

I have used

> 1. mongodb v3.6
> 2. loopback v3
> 3. angular 4

Please someone help or guide, what could be the possible reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem with PM.observe as I understand it is called at each request, and so with each request you have a +1 to the listener model.

it is better to use context for such purposes
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-current-context.html

for example:
server.js or middleware

```
app.remotes().phases.addBefore('invoke', 'options-from-request').use(function(ctx, next) {
        ctx.shared = {};
        let promise;
        let accessToken = ctx.req.accessToken;
        if (accessToken) {
            promise = app.models.OrmUser.findOne({
                where: {
                    id: accessToken.userId
                }
            });
            promise.then(function(result) {
                if (!result) {
                    return next(new Error('No user with this access token was found.')) || null;
                }
                ctx.shared.currentUser = result;
                return Promise.resolve(result);
            }).catch(function(err) {
                return next(err);
            });
        } else {
            promise = Promise.resolve(null);
        }
        promise.then(function(result) {
            let options = ctx.args.options || {};
            options.remoteCtx = ctx;
            ctx.args.options = options;
            return next() || null;
        }).catch(function(err) {
            return next(err) || null;
        });
    });
```

your model:

```
Model.process = function(data, options, cb) {
            if (typeof options == 'function') {
                cb = options;
                options = {};
            }
            cb = cb || utils.createPromiseCallback();

            // from context
            let remoteCtx = options && options.remoteCtx;
            let shared = remoteCtx && remoteCtx.shared;
            let currentUser = shared && shared.currentUser;

            cb(new Error('no impl'));
            return cb.promise;
        };

        Model.remoteMethod('process', {
            accessType: 'WRITE',
            accepts: [{
                arg: 'data',
                type: 'object',
                required: true,
                http: {
                    source: 'body'
                }
            }, {
                arg: 'options',
                type: 'object',
                http: 'optionsFromRequest'
            }],
            http: {
                path: '/process',
                verb: 'post'
            },
            returns: {
                type: Model.modelName,
                root: true
            }
        });
```